# Languages to be used in sketch generation and lip synch

Tags: image, project

i am a final year student of computer engg.i am doing a project on sketch generation from an image.The generated sketch will then be given the feature of lip synch.
I wanted to know what type of programming languages would be suitable for this kind of application?
Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has the answer for this,After a few months of search, i found out myself.The language which can be used are either pure Matlab for image processing and lip sync(however it is difficult in Matlab due to absence of multi threading,but still can be done using a TimerFcn).
Java can be used as language here,but the image processing and sound processing is a bit complicated in Java.
Flash is a language which can be used the best for this type of processing though i doubt if it satisfies the criterion of a 'programming language'.
other readily available tools are present which may be used of the implementation of the project.